# Get the args in Application.launch(Class, String... args)

Tags: java, javafx, parameters, arguments

I am invoking a JavaFX application from java.I  want to use the String arguments in that JavaFX application. How to get that parameters in ChatWithSpecificClient?

For example :

**Invoking Class**

```
public class GenWindow{

public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(ChatWithSpecificClient.class, "String arg");
    }
}
```

**Invoked Class**

```
public class ChatWithSpecificClient extends Application {

    private Parent createScene() {
        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();

        return pane;
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Scene scene = new Scene(createScene());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

}
```

For instance, How to set the title of this window to that argument?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

By using `getRaw()` method of the Parameters class, you can get a String list of arguments passed to the launch method
of Application class. For example if you, invoke the application as.

```
Application.launch(ChatWithSpecificClient.class, "Client's name", "email");
```

Then at the end of the `start(Stage s)` method of your class get these values as a String list.

```
Parameters params = getParameters();
List<String> list = params.getRaw();
System.out.println(list.size());
for(String each : list){
    System.out.println(each);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html#launch-java.lang.String...-):

> args - the command line arguments passed to the application. An application may get these parameters using the [getParameters()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html#getParameters--) method.