# Detect the file my JavaFX program was opened with

Tags: java, javafx

After making an installer to my app, I can make it associate with a file extension, which is great, but I can't figure out how can I detect the path of the file that my program was opened with.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I think it's passed as a command line argument to `main(...)` (and is available via `getParameters()` in the `Application` subclass).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35679904/get-the-args-in-application-launchclass-string-args/35693825

Comment: Also see: [How to get the current working directory in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871051/how-to-get-the-current-working-directory-in-java), similarly for the [user home directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585534/what-is-the-best-way-to-find-the-users-home-directory-in-java/586345), and there is also [`java.class.path`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html): in case any of those are actually what you really need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone having this problem, the file path is the first argument in [`getParameters().getRaw()`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/16/javafx.graphics/javafx/application/Application.Parameters.html#getRaw())

Javadoc description of the function.

> Retrieves a read-only list of the raw arguments. This list may be empty, but is never null. In the case of a standalone application, it is the ordered list of arguments specified on the command line. For named parameters, each <name,value> pair is represented as a single argument of the form: "--name=value".

Thanks, James_D!